# How to remove a part of the string the fastest way

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace the words `int, float, char, bool, main, cin, cout, if, else, else if, for, while, clrscr, getch, do, void` to `""` (like removing it) if it is found on the string.

So if i have the ff:

```
str = "main(){  clrscr(); couts<<"wrong"; cout<<"right";  }"
```

After replacing, it should be:

```
str = "(){  ();  couts<<"wrong"; <<"right"; }"
```

So far what i've tried is (wrong of course):

```
str = str.replace(/\s+(?:int|char|bool|main|float)/, "");//summarized
```

Comment: Make your regex global, but how do you want to deal with `couts`? What specifically should prevent it from being replaced?

Comment: couts must stay there and i'll deal with it using another condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `g` modifier to perform multiple replacements on the string. You should use the `\b` regexp at both ends of the regexp to match word boundaries. So it should be:

```
str = str.replace(/\b(int|char|bool|main|float|...)\b/g, "");
```

Comment: where is my ?: and the \s+?

Comment: `?:` isn't needed. And `\s+` would prevent removing `main` in your example, since there's no space before it; I think `\b` serves the purpose you intended with that.

Comment: @fireflieslive the `\s+` is replaced by the `\b`, which is more precise for what you want to achieve. The main distinction is that with `\s+`, it will also replace predecing spaces since the spaces are part of the match. Also, it would not match any of you words if they were at the beginning of the string. Finally, I am not sure about this, but I think it's still good to make the group non-capturing for performance reasons.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496499/how-to-remove-a-part-of-the-string-using-arrays

Answer (score 0):

Use the word boundary `\b` as well as the global flag `g`.

```
'main(){  clrscr(); couts<<"wrong"; cout<<"right";  }'.replace(/\b(?:int|float|char|bool|main|cin|cout|if|else|else if|for|while|clrscr|getch|do|void)\b/g, '');
```

In you regex, `\s+` would prevent matching words at the beginning of the string, since you used the `+` repetition operator, which means *at least one*. You could always have replaced the `\s+` by `(\s+|^)`, but you would still be left with one problem: the spaces would be part of the match and they would get replaced as well. Therefore, `\b` which matches word boundaries serves you better.